# Is there a reason for using pure virtual destructor except for deleting dynamically allocated memory inside derived classes?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
};

Base::~Base() {};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    ~Derived() override
    {
        std::cout << "Deleting Dynamically allocated Memory" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

I'm interested in how I can use pure virtual destructors. How to use, and when to use.

Comment: There's a much easier way to look at this. Try: "I would like to make sure that I fully understand what this means and how this works, so when I need to have a class with a virtual destructor, for whatever reason, I will know exactly what to do".

Comment: Deleting owned memory is a valid reason for implementing a destructor. It has nothing to do with it being or not being pure `virtual`. Having a pure `virtual` destructor is independent of implementing a non-`default` destructor.

Comment: AFAIK, you can use a pure virtual destructor when: 1) you need a base not to be instantiable, 2) you don't have/want any other pure virtual member functions, and 3) you need your classes to be _polymorphic_. Note that such classes does not affect only deletion through base-class pointer. They affect, e.g., also the usage of `dynamic_cast` etc.

Comment: Formally, if you `new` an object of a derived type and you delete it through a pointer to the base, the destructor in the base class must be virtual.

Comment: @PeteBecker virtual yes, but not necessarily *pure* virtual, which is the question at hand. Two different concepts. The only thing a *pure* virtual does is force the derived type to `override` the virtual with a new implementation, nothing more. That is not necessary just to get polymorphic behavior in general.

Comment: @RemyLebeau — yes, that’s why that was a **comment** and not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your class to be abstract (and therefore a polymorphic type) *and* behave itself when instances of derived classes are deleted using a base class pointer then making the destructor pure virtual is an option.

But you must provide a function body for the destructor else program linkage will fail (destructors cannot be *overridden*). A particularly nice way to achieve all this is

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
};
Base::~Base() = default;
```

(The language doesn't provide a way to make the destructor pure virtual *and* specify the compiler default in one statement.)

Comment: `virtual ~Base() = default;` is a better option imo.

Comment: @IlCapitano: But then it ain't pure virtual, so the class is not abstract, unless you write another pure virtual function of course. And `Base::~Base() {};` has issues of its own.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you want a class to be abstract. Only way to make a class abstract is to declare a member function pure virtual. If your class has no other member functions, then at least it has a destructor. In such case, only member function that can be made pure is the destructor.

As far as I know, there is no other reason to declare a virtual destructor as pure.